# How 'google analytics web' knows name of mobile device with javascript?

Tags: javascript, mobile, web, google-analytics

[image: from google analytics page]

Hi.

I'm tracking some mobile pages with google analytics. 
And I found an interesting thing that google knows which devices visited the pages.

How google analytics detects specific device name (model name like Samsung SHV-E250S) with javascript not only device type(iPhone, Android or Windows)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From browser's UserAgent, we can achieve model number(such as iPhone OS 3_0, LG-L160L) of the device.
So from that data, google can assume what device is it.

Comment: It's more than that. From useragent, iPad & iPad Pro should look the same. Google Analytics can track them separately, though.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open source solution called WURFL which has a database of devices. If you were looking to replicate this system you could use a server side API that WURFL supports and query the user string which can return the make and model.

http://wurfl.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 1):

Self-answer

I found model name in userAgent like below.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.2; SHV-E210S Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.92 Mobile Safari/537
```

Comment: @Basic Yes. My friend told me.